# how to get the ID from a data table using c# code

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDWzZ.png)

I am new in c# and I need help in getting the ID

here is my code

I am using a listbox and my listbox name is _1stGrpA. I need to get the Id from my tblMatch1

tblMatch1 is my table that contains my ID. how to get the ID ?

```
tblMatch1 = adpMatch1.Get1stInGroupA();

_1stGrpA.ItemsSource = tblMatch1;
_1stGrpA.DisplayMemberPath = "TeamName";
```

I want to get the ID from tblMatch1

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Please don't post images, What do you mean by `ID`? Is it a property of whatever type `tblMatch1` holds a list of (inferred from the code)? More information is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
lstBox.SelectedValuePath = "Id"
var selectedId = lstBox.SelectedValue; // Output selectedId
```